# lightning:inputRichText & lightning:formattedRichText isn't working with email Template Body

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am having text EmailTemplates in my org where body contains new lines but when I copy the **EmailTemplate** body to **lightning:inputRichText, lightning:formattedRichText** either it is displaying it in one line.

```
<div>
    <lightning:formattedRichText aura:id="richText1" value="{!v.templateText}"/>
    <lightning:inputRichText aura:id="richText2" value="{!v.templateText}"/>
    <aura:unescapedHtml aura:id="richText3" value="{!v.templateText}"/>
</div>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Are you using \n for line breaks? If so try with its HTML counterpart: <p> or <br>. Also read about 'Supported HTML Tags' in [lightning:inputRichText](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:inputRichText/documentation) documentation

Comment: I am just fetching EmailTemplate body and showing it to the above input elements. Even its a Text type EmailTemplate still user can enter text with line breaks.

Comment: I finally found a solution for the above problem. Wrap the above tags in <pre> html tag it will work properly.

Comment: great, you could answer your own question. It may help others facing similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is some tweaks in this scenario it is not possible with lightning tag alone I just wrapped lightning:inputRichText inside pre html tag and it worked.

```
<pre><lightning:formattedRichText aura:id="richText1" value="{!v.templateText}"/></pre>
<pre><lightning:inputRichText aura:id="richText2" value="{!v.templateText}"/></pre>
<pre><aura:unescapedHtml aura:id="richText3" value="{!v.templateText}"/></pre>
```

It can work with other lightning tag as well.